# PC on and off loop , the longest it can stay is 30 minutes then automatically turn off and on again

Tags: boot, ssd, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

1. Went to three repair shops - 2 said its motherboard & 1 said power supply when I request to repair the motherboard, but they don't have tools to confirm it if its really PSU issue.
2. Asking one more repairman before send the pc, he said its might be processor or motherboard.
3. Seems like I can't find place to fix or diagnose it. It has been a year since this issue happen.
4. I'm thinking to buy new processor and motherboard but I hope I can diagnose which one is actually broken.

Here the symptoms:

1. Sometimes on for few seconds only before start on off looping.
2. One fan pin is not functioning (processor fan is connected to the functioned pin).
3. Processor fan is on every time its making the on loop.
4. No beep from motherboard.
5. It start happen after hdd is corrupted, and sent to change to ssd.
6. Notice that, CPU led on motherboard is blinking one time before pc shut down - not sure if this info is helpful.

My PC specs and conditions:

1. Customized build - 8gb ddr4, motherboard MSI B150M mortar, Intel i7, PSU V550 Cooler Master, 2 sata ssd.
2. Built in 2016/17. Can't remember.
3. Start having this issue since early 2020.
4. Not heavily use - image processing, coding, some light gaming.
5. Never made any hardware changes except for SSD, which is both changed last year.

Comment: Testing suggestions: Install minimum possible hardware (PSU, MB+CPU, 1 stick RAM, no storage, minimal support required to get the video to show POST on a screen, no / no other cards).  See if the problem will reproduce.  If not, start plugging in additional items one at a time until you can get the problem to reproduce (probably the most recently added device is the problem).  If the minimal setup has issues, swap the cheapest of the MB or the PSU for new, and try again.  If it still happens, you picked the wrong item to swap out; the other one is the likely culprit.  Good luck!

Comment: I did try this before (install the min. hw only) but it still happen. The guy did check the ram also and he said it has no issue. But I haven't try swap psu, mb or processor yet. I don't have extra component for these.

Answer (score 0):

I bring to where it was born in 2016. Get great and exact explanations and services from them.

The guy explain to me that my processor is too old as now we have 10th gen processor. Its hard to find or no more motherboard that can support 6th gen processor. The same model also no longer manufactured.

He help me test with their PSU and the issue still happen. He think the motherboard is the problem. So he advice me either to build new pc (new motherboard, processor and ram - I can't remember if ram also is outdated for new board)  or find secondhand motherboard that have same socket (150).

I'm being positive that his diagnose is correct straight find secondhand motherboard online, which I replace the old one with msi night elf. The guy help me to install it and yesterday I run it from afternoon until this morning with only chrome is opened while downloading a 6gb installer. yeah, I guess it fixed and working fine.

But I still not sure what is the problem with the old board. It might short circuited by external fan, not sure. Planning to send it for fix or sell it.